# How do I remove class from siblings using pure javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to js. Trying to avoid jQuery for this project. 
My goal is to add an "active" class to a targeted element when a button is clicked, while removing the active class from any of its siblings. One struggle I've had is problems with involves document.getElementByClassName(), which claims not to be a function.

// HTML

```
<path id="el1" class="btn" onclick="revealPanel()">
<path id="el2" class="btn" onclick="revealPanel()">

<g id="el1_box" class="box"></g>
<g id="el2_box" class="box"></g>
```

// JS

```
function revealBox() {

  document.getElementsByClassName("box").classList.remove("active");

  var myId = event.target.id;
  var boxNum = myId + "_box";

  document.getElementById(boxNum).classList.add("active"); 
}
```

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName()` does not return a single element and does not have a `.classList` property

Comment: There's no `.classList` property on a collection. You need a loop. Why are you not using `myId` or `boxNum`? What are `reading` and `panel`? Why is the function name different?

Comment: ...your use of the global `event` object will fail in some browsers. Define it as a property of the event handler, and pass it in from the call site.

Comment: I edited the id's. Should have been 'boxNum'

Answer (score 1):

`.getElementsByClassName()` does not return a single element and does not have a `.classList` property.

You can iterate the result of [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and set the `.classList` for each element of the `HTMLCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an update that seems to be working, or at least moving in the right direction:

```
function revealBox() {

  var boxSiblings = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  while (boxSiblings.length)
  boxSiblings[0].classList.remove("active");

  var myId = event.target.id;
  var boxNum = myId + "_box";

 document.getElementById(boxNum).classList.add("active"); 
}
```

Comment: I set a new variable that allows me to remove the active class from all elements before adding it back to the box currently targeted.